# How to get Object from HttpResponse?

Tags: java

I'm trying to send an object from server to client.

client side:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

server side:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(new Object());
}
```

How do I get the object from the response?
Do i need to use instead:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```

if so which way is more efficient?
example code please :)
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant just send Object.toString() because it does not contain all information about the object.
Serialisation is probably what you need. Take a look at that: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/
The Object you want to send has to implement Serializable.
On your server you can then use something like this:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
oos.writeObject(yourSerializableObject);
```

On the client side you do:

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent()); //Android
in = new ObjectInputStream(response.getInputStream()); //Java
ObjcetClass obj = (ObjectClass)in.readObject();
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can serialize using JSON, there are several projects like jackson http://jackson.codehaus.org/, Gson that can serialize objects quite easily. Cross-platform and easy to debug.

Comment: I thought that becuase out.print() get object it really sends one, but now i know better, Thanks.  
about the code above i guess you meant:  
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  
instead of:  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
and HttpResponse don't have getOutputStream()  
so my problem remains

Comment: Oh, yes i meant that. For the response i think you have to use `response.getInputStream()`

Comment: response.getEntity().getContent() is the only way to get InputStream. is it good?

Comment: You are programming for Android, right? Yes, I guess this is fine.